# Using French-issued Schengen visa for a trip to Italy

Tags: visas, schengen, france, italy

I have a multiple-entry Schengen visa issued by France. I applied for that visa because I was planning to attend a meeting in France, which was postponed, so this visa is unused. I am planning a trip to Italy next week.

Will face any problems since I never used that visa for France?

I am still planning to use it for France and that trip will be longer than my planned trip to Italy.

In this case, is it a good idea to bring a paper showing that the event has been postponed, and that I already bought my plane ticket back from Italy?

Side note: I am not planning to continue my trip to France after going to Italy, so this is not a first entry point question (I know that first entry can be different from the country that issued the visa); there will be two separate trips.

Comment: @blackbird, I am not planning to continue to France after Italy, I will have two separate trips, which is I believe a different question than first entry point questions.

Comment: Thanks @pnuts, I changed it. I know even if I go to France they always have the chance to reject me, depending on the officer's decision at the border. I am just trying to understand how unlikely is it to be rejected in practice.

Comment: @tahsintahsin the proposed duplicate question is not about continuing to one country after another; it is not about the first point of entry in a given trip; it is about whether the first trip should be to the country issuing the visa.  In your case, the country issuing the visa is France and the first trip is to Italy.  It really is a direct match of the proposed duplicate.

Comment: Thanks @phoog, I thought that question was for first entry.

Comment: @tahsintahsin the highest-voted answers actually address the first-point-of-entry question rather than the one actually asked.  I'm retracting my close vote.

Comment: Thank you very much @pnuts for providing great feedback.